# Please help querying for room's availability

Tags: mysql, sql

I wish to develop a meeting room reservation system.

So far I have designed the database as follow.

**rooms:**

1. id
2. room_desc

**periods:**

- id
- period_desc

**reservations:**

- id
- room_id
- reservation_date
- start_period_id
- end_period_id

When making a reservation, the system will write down the `start_period_id`, `end_period_id` the user reserves for.

When a user want to make a new reservation, he/she will specify the date and started-ended period he/she wants, the system should give him/her a list a rooms which have not been reserved during the specified period of time.

I came up with some SQL but it didn't work for some [circumstance](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9adae0/15) so I guess, it's still wrong.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9adae0/1)

Please help with SQL for querying the room's availability.

Comment: And what are these circumstance? What is your input and expected output for this scenario?

Comment: what's capacity? Do you want to discount one unit from the capacity if the period matches the query? or you don't want to display the room at all?

Comment: capacity in my system means number of people the meeting can contain, but right now i think the most difficult for me is to query the periods so i left the capacity and the date criteria for later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d07965/20

Use this query. Only thing you are missing is equality condition. :

```
select * 
from rooms A 
  left join reservations B
on A.id = B.room_id 
and B.reservation_date = '2014-01-11'
and B.start_period_id <= 11 and B.end_period_id >= 11
where B.room_id is null;
```

Regards,
Mansi